# In honor of Olof Palme’s birthday, January 30

Tags: alphametic

Olof Palme, the prime minister of Sweden, was born on January 30, 1927.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olof_Palme

Each Swedish flag can be assigned arbitrary digit.

[image: alphametic puzzle about Olof Palme]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is,

> [image: 78691÷30]

Start noting that

> every multiple of 30 has a 0 at the end.
>
>  [image: 2]

Notice that the number right below P can be

> 3 or 6, but it cannot be 9 because P>9. Therefore O is either 1 or 2.
>
>  [image: 3]

> .. but O=1 leads to contradiction.
>
>  [image: 4]

> So O=2.

Then some digits can be filled up immediately.

> [image: 5]

And finally

> F=1,2, or 3 but since different letters represent different digits, only 3 leads to a  valid solution.

Comment: Very nice. One thing you seemed to have overlooked: The circled number in your second spoiler is the value of E, and that leaves only one option for O.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

Computer based solution:

---

Div1 Results Set 1
baseX = 10

---

**Solution 1:**
NonParticipants
Digits: 4 5
At Loop 192071
Time elapsed:
00:00:00.0895476.

> `2623 
>      ------ 
>  30 | 78691 
>      -60    
>       --    
>       186   
>      -180   
>       ---   
>         69  
>        -60  
>         --  
>          91 
>         -90 
>          -- 
>           1`

**Solution 2:**
NonParticipants
Digits: 4 5 9
At Loop 193071
Time elapsed:
00:00:00.0907272

> `2621 
>      ------ 
>  30 | 78631 
>      -60    
>       --    
>       186   
>      -180   
>       ---   
>         63  
>        -60  
>         --  
>          31 
>         -30 
>          -- 
>           1`

1680000 Loops
Time elapsed:
00:00:00.5145666

---

resolved by:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companyname.razkmoshed

Comment: Please take a look at your answer's formatting. Is this how you intended it?